# Qt/Win Creating app shortcuts

Tags: c++, windows, qt, lnk

In Qt I know you can create a shortcut (lnk) using the following method

```
QFile::link("myapp.exe", "myapp.exe.lnk");
```

This works fine but I want to create an lnk that also has some arguments in the target path. Anyway to do this in Qt?

Comment: Suggested edit? This comment is not constructive nor adds any additional information to the original problem and/or solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following answer from Constantin Makshin in the [Qt-interest mailing list](http://lists.qt.nokia.com/public/qt-interest/2010-January/017337.html):

> QFile::link() function creates symbolic links (speaking in terms of
>   Unix-like systems) and Windows shortcuts is only a more or less equal
>   solution. And since symbolic links don't support command line arguments
>   (they are simply "the same file with different name"), QFile::link()
>   doesn't support them either.
>
> So you'll have to rely on native API to create such shortcuts/links.

Apart from using the native API, you could also create a `.bat` file and store the command line call in there.