# QFile create link to file with arguments

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5, shortcut

I want to create a link to a file using the `QFile::link()` method. It works with files without any argument, but now I need to link to an `.exe` file with arguments.

```
QFile(qApp->applicationFilePath()).link(QDir().homePath() + QString("/Desktop/AppArg.lnk"))
```

My problem is that I can't set any arguments in the destination path.

I've tried:

```
QFile(qApp->applicationFilePath() + " argument").link(QDir().homePath() + QString("/Desktop/AppArg.lnk"))
```

The shortcut looks like this:

[image: that]

but it should look like this:

[image: that]

Is there any way to create a link / shortcut with arguments?

Comment: Related but old: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401404/qt-win-creating-app-shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401404/qt-win-creating-app-shortcuts) Not sure if there is any current Qt support.

Comment: You may have to resort to this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906974/how-to-programmatically-create-a-shortcut-using-win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906974/how-to-programmatically-create-a-shortcut-using-win32)

Comment: Don't bother with `Qt::link()` for this.  [Use `IShellLink` directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/links) instead, so you can call its [`SetPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishelllinkw-setpath) and [`SetArguments()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishelllinkw-setarguments) methods separately.